# To print GunZip FileName and selected rows -Continuation :

Tags: unix, awk

Would like to print first 2 rows from all the files located in the directory along with File Name.
All are *.gz extension files. Having around 100 files in that directory.

sample_jan.csv.gz

```
10,Jan,100
30,Jan,300
50,Jan,500
```

sample_feb.csv.gz

```
10,Feb,200
20,Feb,400
40,Feb,800
60,Feb,1200
```

Expected Output:

```
Filename:sample_jan.csv.gz
10,Jan,100
30,Jan,300

Filename:sample_feb.csv.gz
10,Feb,200
20,Feb,400
```

Tried below command where as Filename appears Blank

```
zcat sample_jan.csv.gz | awk 'FNR==1{print "Filename:" FILENAME} FNR<3' > Output.txt

Filename:-
10,Jan,100
30,Jan,300
```

Tried below command where as Filename appears Wrong

```
awk 'FNR==1{print "Filename:" FILENAME} FNR<3' <(gzip -dc sample_jan.csv.gz) > Output.txt

Filename:/dev/fd/63
10,Jan,100
30,Jan,300
```

Looking for your suggestions, dont have perl & python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this one-liner,

```
for file in *.gz; do echo "Filename: $file"; zcat "$file" | head -2 ; done
```